# Grid expanding in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid

Hai
presently i have grid like this.

```
    <Grid  Name="tGrid1"  Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" >
    </Grid>



    <Grid Name="Grid2"  Grid.Row="1"  Background="LightBlue" >
    </Grid>



    <Grid Name="Grid3"  Grid.Row="2" Background="LightGray" Height="auto" >

    </Grid>




    <Grid Name="Grid4"   Grid.Row="3"   Background="LightGreen" >
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" Margin="13.5,5,0,5" Name="TestBtn" Width="50" Click="test_Click" >Test</Button>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

What i want is, when i click the Test button Grid 1 and Grid 2 has to collapsed and the space has to be occupied with Grid 3.That means the out of total height of 500 of Outer Grid , Grid 3 should occupy height=465 and Grid 4 should ocupy Height=35.
How can i do this? How should i change my height definitions of Grid ?
Thanx in advance
Kaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai 
i found the solution.

```
  <DockPanel  >
 <Grid  Name="tGrid1"  Grid.Row="0" DockPanel.dock="Top" Background="Black" >
 </Grid>

 <Grid Name="Grid2"  Grid.Row="1"  DockPanel.dock="Top" Background="LightBlue" >
 </Grid>

<Grid Name="Grid4"   Grid.Row="3"  DockPanel.dock="Bottom"  Background="LightGreen" >
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" Margin="13.5,5,0,5" Name="TestBtn" Width="50" Click="test_Click" >Test</Button>
 </Grid>

<Grid Name="Grid3"  Grid.Row="2" DockPanel.dock="Top" Background="LightGray" Height="auto" >

</Grid>
</DockPanel>




 private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     tGrid1.visibility=visibility.collapsed;
Grid2.visibility=Visibility.collapsed;
  }
```

This works fine.
Thank you
Kaja

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but in the `test_Click` method you could use this:

```
  private void test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     tGrid1.Width = 0;
     tGrid1.Height = 0;
     Grid2.Width = 0;
     Grid2.Height = 0;

     Grid3.Height = 465;
     Grid4.Height = 35;
  }
```

If by "collapse" you mean "hide", this will work by setting the `height` and `width` on  `tGrid1` and `Grid2` to 0.

Comment: this is not working.Its removes the Grid1 and Grid2 but the Grid3 is not expanded.
Anyway thanku 4 ur time.Let me know if u find any other way